# Angular2 DomSanitizer issue

Tags: angular, typescript, inline-styles, angular-dom-sanitizer

I am trying to use *background-image* inline for my **ngFor* list items.
Im my Component Class I declare a variable which stores a common part of my images URL  (say, it's *http://storage.com/*) and also unique parts of URLs of the images as **this.image** (say, they are 
*qwerty/01.jpg, 
uiop/02.jpg, 
asdfg/03.jpg*, 
etc)

All together it looks like

```
export class AppComponent {
cartItems: any;
image: any;

constructor(public cartService: CartService, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

ngOnInit(){
let sanitizedUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('http://storage.com/' + this.image);

  this.cartService.getCartItems().subscribe(
     (data) => this.cartItems = data
  );

}
```

In the view I have where **cartItem** is an item over generated **ngFor* list:

```
<span class="col cart__item--imageBox" 
[style.background-image.url]="('sanitizedUrl' + cartItem.image)">
</span>
```

Console shows warnings:

```
WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value sanitizedUrl<<here go the images URLs endings - qwerty/01.jpg, uiop/02.jpg, asdfg/03.jpg, etc >> (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).
```

I supposed the URL to be "sanitized".

What should be done to be able to use *background-image* styles inline as in my example above?

**UPD!
I rewrote my NgOnInit function into that:**

```
ngOnInit(){
let addSanitizedUrl = (cartItem) => {
      cartItem.sanitizedImageUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('https://s27.postimg.org/' + this.image + cartItem.image)
      return cartItem;
    };

this.cartService.getCartItems().subscribe(
    (data) => this.cartItems = data.map(addSanitizedUrl) ngOnInit(){
let addSanitizedUrl = (cartItem) => {
      cartItem.sanitizedImageUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('https://s27.postimg.org/' + this.image + cartItem.image)
      return cartItem;
    };

  this.cartService.getCartItems().subscribe(
      (data) => this.cartItems = data.map(addSanitizedUrl)
  );

}
```

The Warnings disappeared, but it seems like the app doesn't find any of my images passed in the service. Just can't find them via DevTools Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Only a part of your URL is sanitized. To fully **sanitize** it,

Add a method to your component for sanitization as

```
sanitize(url:string){
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
  }
```

and you HTML will be calling the above method before URL is passed as below

```
<span class="col cart__item--imageBox" 
[style.background-image.url]="sanitize('sanitizedUrl' + cartItem.image)">
</span>
```

Also it is just a warning and can be ignored.

Comment: Updated!
I sanitized the style in each of my objects (since I have no more warnings in console), but I can't get the images rendered in the view (I can't find them either in the Inspector).
And I can't ignore those warnings, because the images are blocked to get rendered.

Comment: what do you mean by images are blocked ?

Comment: I mean that they are not rendered. I suppose, because of the warnings for unsafe url / style

Comment: are you available in teamviewer?

Comment: I've got no Teamviewer

Comment: I may be wrong here, but isn't bypassSecurityTrustUrl used to byepass sanitization